# apache camel: replace function

Tags: replace, apache-camel, transform

I want to use replace function in apache camel but have trouble with this. here is my code:

```
"firstName" : "aaa",
"lastName" : []
```

and  my desire output is like this:

```
"firstName" : "aaa",
"lastName" : ""
```

I use this code for transform:

```
<transform> 
<simple>${body.replace("[]","")}</simple> 
</transform>
```

but the problem is not showing double quotation, actually I get this:

```
"firstName" : "aaa",
"lastName" :
```

I used &quot  also, but do not work. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried putting single quotes outside the double quotes? so `<simple>${body.replace("[]",'""')}</simple>` . Also, are you trying to match a String? There is a difference between `[]` and `"[]"`

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes I have tested (' " " ') also, but no gain.
actually in my test there is no differences between  [] and "[]", both of them replace [] with nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the correct replace call would contain escaped double quotes (I use Java DSL)

```
.transform(simple("${body.replace('[]', '\"\"')}"))
```

But that **does not work**, the empty double quotes do not show up in the result. Perhaps they are "evaluated to empty".

```
Original body: "firstName" : "aaa" "lastName" : []
Transformed body: "firstName" : "aaa" "lastName" :
```

However, you can do a **workaround** by replacing empty brackets in a **first step** to empty double quotes with a **"special helper character"** just to make sure the replace string cannot be interpreted as empty. I used the plus sign (+) in my example below.

In a **second step** you can **replace the helper character with nothing** and so the empty double quotes stay in the result.

```
.transform(simple("${body.replace('[]', '+\"\"')}"))
.transform(simple("${body.replace('+', '')}"))
```

This works for me.

```
Original body: "firstName" : "aaa" "lastName" : []
Transformed body: "firstName" : "aaa" "lastName" : ""
```

You would need to use a **helper character that is not contained in your body**. Otherwise the second step would perhaps remove something you do not want to.